# what could be wrong with this code? Not running as expected

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm

Running assembly code using TASM in DOSOX. I'm trying to print my name at the center of the monitor. The letters should be printed as such: first letter, then every previous letter starting from the first should be displayed as well as the current letter e.g name = carlton

first print c
then c and a
then c,a,r
then c,a,r,l etc

;here's what I tried.
;I get an infinite loop and nothing close to the intended result.Think my approach is ok but the coding has ;many problems.

```
.MODEL SMALL
    .STACK 64
    .DATA
my_string db "Carlton", 0
count1 db 07
buffer db 07 dup(0)
count2  dw 0ffffh   ;delay
.CODE
MAIN:   mov ax,@DATA
    mov ds,ax
; initialize pointer to point to my_string
   mov bx, offset my_string
   mov di, offset buffer

outer_loop: ; outer loop to iterate through each letter 
;clearing the screen
    MOV AX,0600H    ;scroll the entire page
    MOV BH,07   ;normal attribute
    MOV CX,0000     ;row and column of the top left
    MOV DX,184FH    ;row and column of the bottom right
    INT 10H     ;invoke interrupt 10H
    
    ;setting the cursor to the center of the screen
    MOV AH,02   ;set cursor option
    MOV BH,00   ;page 0
    MOV DL,39   ;center column position
    MOV DH,12   ;center row position
    INT 10H     ;invoke interrupt 10H


        ; print current letter
       
        mov di,[bx] ; store current character in di, wc pionts to buffer
        mov ah,09
        mov dx, di
        int 21h
    dec count2  ;decrement delay
    jnz outer_loop

        ; inner loop to print buffer before current letter
         print_prev:  
       cmp di,[bx]
       je next          
           mov ah, 09
           mov dx, di
           int 21h
           inc di
       jmp print_prev

       ; increment pointer to next letter
        next:
    inc bx
    dec count1
    mov count2,0ffffh
        jnz outer_loop

 ; exit program
    mov ah,4ch
    int 21h
    END MAIN
```

Comment: For starters, ah=09h, int 21h will print an entire string up to a dollar sign. If there is no dollar sign for a terminator, it'll try to print whatever is there indefinitely.

Comment: @ArthurKalliokoski.Thought the string will be stored char by char in the data segment. Thanks though. can you help point out what else is messed up in there?

Comment: Try loading each char into AL and using int 29h

Answer (score 0):

### point out what else is messed up in there?

- Even before trying to print the first letter will ";clearing the screen" and ";setting the cursor to the center of the screen" have destroyed your BX pointer! Remember that BH (that you used for an attribute and display page number) is the top part of the BX register.
- You seem to think that the DOS function 09h displays a single character. This is not so: this function displays a string of characters ending with a $-sign (and the $-sign itself is not displayed at all). For single-character output use the DOS function 02h.
- Your *outer_loop* might easily be called an infinite loop, as it will clear the screen 65535 times and show some garbage characters.
- If your *print_prev* loop is expected to print individual letters, then what do you expect from `inc di` that logically would be incrementing a character?
- `mov di,[bx] ; store current character in di` clearly demonstrates a misconception about pointers and square brackets. This particular instruction loads DI with **2** characters from the string and at the same time is destroying the buffer pointer you had setup in DI.

### on a more constructive note

It is not clear what exactly it is that you want to output to the screen,
but from your mention:

> first print c then c and a then c,a,r then c,a,r,l etc

I take it that you could be looking for:

```
wait 1 sec
1st screen:  c
wait 1 sec
2nd screen:  ca
wait 1 sec
3rd screen:  car
wait 1 sec
4th screen:  carl
wait 1 sec
5th screen:  carlt
wait 1 sec
6th screen:  carlto
wait 1 sec
7th screen:  carlton
```

Next code as an example:

```
  ;clearing the screen

  ;setting the cursor to the center of the screen

  ; showing the name one character at a time
  mov  si, offset my_string
TheLoop:
  ; Wait 1 sec
  mov  ah, 2Ch     ; DOS.GetSystemTime
  int  21h         ; -> CX DX
  mov  bl, dh      ; Keep seconds
NotYet:
  mov  ah, 2Ch     ; DOS.GetSystemTime
  int  21h         ; -> CX DX
  cmp  dh, bl      ; Did seconds change ? 
  je   NotYet
  ; Show next character, previous characters already in place
  mov  dl, [si]
  mov  ah, 02h     ; DOS.DisplayCharacter
  int  21h
  inc  si
  dec  count1
  jnz  TheLoop
```